# Text Box Value Assignment Suddently Doesn't Work

Tags: excel, textbox, vba

I have a workbook I'm opening in Excel 2010.  The VBA code in it has been running smoothly for the last five months.  All of a sudden, I'm getting weird errors.

The most frustrating one is the assignment of the value in a *TextBox* when the user navigates to the tab.  On open, I'm trying to update the value of a search *TextBox* to the value of a cell the user may have set via the *TextBox* on one of the other tabs.  The range in question is a single cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    ActiveSheet.ScatterCustomerSearch.Value = _
        Worksheets("Selection Sheet").Range("Customer_Search").Value     
End Sub
```

The value assignment, which has worked just fine before now, all of a sudden gives me a `438 error`, saying the `object doesn't support this property or method`.  It did before, but all of a sudden doesn't now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you `Dim newValue : newValue = Worksheets("Selection Sheet").Range("Customer_Search").Value : ScatterCustomerSearch.Value = newValue`, you would find out if the problem is in retrieving the value or in assigning it.

Comment: Looks like it's the assignment.  When I added that code, the ScatterCustomerSearch.Value = newValue gives me a 424-object-required error

Comment: Now right click on `newValue` and select **Add watch ...**, then do the same with `ScatterCustomerSearch.Value` and tell me which **Type** they are

Comment: newValue is listed as Variant/Empty, and ScatterCustomerSearch is listed as Empty

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention you should inspect them when running the code. Put a break point at `ScatterCustomerSearch.Value = newValue`

Comment: The values are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could possibly be the dreaded [Microsoft update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036/EN-US).

Close all office applications, then delete this file:

C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0\MSForms.exd

This is a temp file, it will be re-created when opening Excel again. See if this fixes your problem.